# What CSS property is controlling this input highlighting?

Tags: css, input, highlighting

The image below shows an input field with the text 'test' in it, immediately after clicking in the input to gain focus:
[image]

I'm trying to remove the green highlighting (the green is coming from the OS highlight color). Here is another image illustrating the desired behavior with a normal, unstyled input:
[image]

As you can see, the standard behavior is a cursor appearing where the user clicked, as opposed to highlighting the entire text with no cursor. What is causing this behavior?

The styling for this element is scattered all over the place, and inspecting the computed properties doesn't seem to reveal anything unusual to me. This behavior is present in Chrome and Firefox.
[image]

Comment: This input is using jQuery UI autocomplete, but based on their examples and documentation, that doesn't seem to be a behavior autocomplete is responsible for.

Comment: I have used firebug as a good solution to distinguishing CSS rules, as it displays which rules are applied and where they come from, down to the line number and file. Have you tried using firebug or a similar developer overlay (not the default chrome one, that's crap)?

Comment: https://getfirebug.com/downloads

Comment: `-webkit-user-select` and its buddies are the CSS rules for styling the selection

Comment: What I think you want to do is use javascript to `collapse` the selection when the input gets focus. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/collapse

Comment: @Martin I installed Firebug and am seeing the same list of properties - nothing stands out as unusual.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I think you're on to something. It looks like something is modifying the selection on focus or click, and overriding the default behavior.

Comment: I am just guessing here, but could it be to do with css selection colour?? `*:selection {background: blue;}`

Comment: @Aaron That was my first guess, but the highlighting color is actually coming from the OS, not from the CSS.

Comment: @AlexMcMillan You ended up leading me to the correct answer - it wasn't anything to do with CSS, but an event listener that was intercepting focus and calling select().  If you want to add that as an answer, I'll select it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears something is `select`ing the text on focus.  You could use javascript to `collapse` the selection on focus.

http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/collapse